# How to create custom content elements in typo3 using a sitepackage?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, flux, fluid

I'm using the sitepackage builder to create website in Typo3 9.5. Right now i need to create a custom content element and i just can't get it to work.

I followed several tutorials, including the official doc (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html) and it seems like there's always missing an obvious part i don't get. For example the first part in the doc "PageTsconfig", where exactly am i supposed to put this code?

If anyone can provide a dummy step by step manual to create and use a custom content element, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately we cannot develop something for you. Please try to narrow down your issue to a single question by appending what you've done already and why it doesn't work (eg. error messages) in your post.

Comment: [Here](https://usetypo3.com/custom-fsc-element.html) is the best solution for this, thanks to @daniel!

Answer (score 1):

The Page TS Config Part goes for example into the page properties resources (Edit page in page tree). Usually you place this TS part into your custom extension and just add it as a file in the mentioned section. The Page TS Config for custom elements is responsible for displaying your content element options when clicking "Add new" content element on a page.

You can have a look at my extension at Github which is just a base content element "Text with image on left". There you should find all necessary steps in order to create your own content element. I have just adjusted the extension in order to have v9 compatibility. If any questions or you get stuck somewhere, just let me know.

https://github.com/paravista/custom_content_element

Another advice it to check out the mask extension and mask exporter extension. The generated exported code can also be a good source in order to see how it has been done here.

Comment: Thanks for the mask tipp, i finally got it to work somehow. I now got a seperate extension for my custom content element. But it should be possible to integrate the content element directly into my sitepackage right?

Comment: Yes sure, this is possible. I always integrate my custom content elements directly into my general sitepackage. Just have a look at my Github extension. If you basically include the files there into your provider extension, taking care of the namespace / extension key of course, you should be able to easily set it up.